# Can I get a PhD if I'm more interested in practical implementation aspects?

Tags: phd, thesis, computer-science, artificial-intelligence

Let's say, as an example, that I started a PhD in a lab which works with artificial intelligence, and I'm in a position to work with neural networks. If I'm more interested on implementing neural networks on very constrained devices (let's say, low processing power and small memory), could that contribute to my thesis?

**Some background**

Here's some more context.

I started in a PhD program a little over a year ago. Let's say I hold a bachelor degree in CS, and the only experience I have with artificial intelligence and neural networks comes from coursework.

Over the past year, I've been studying the topic and I have being implementing some of the methods and algorithms that I came across. What I feel is that I'm very interested and I enjoy implementing these methods in systems where processing power and memory are very limited. This forces me to look at the algorithm and at my system, and think of how I could better match them. This could mean taking advantage of the particular architecture of my system or a particular characteristic of the algorithm. This is something that I have some experience with.

Compared to how I feel about implementing these algorithms and methods, I feel only moderately interested in trying to come up with novel algorithms and methods and diving deep into the theory of neural networks.

For the other students in the lab, it is quite the opposite: they're focusing more on coming up with novel algorithms and theory and they really don't care about implementation aspects. As long as it works, it is fine. I have the impression that the other students look down on me, and I have heard that focusing in implementation aspects is more of a job for technicians or bachelor/master students, not PhD students. However, I do believe that getting deep into implementation details requires a lot of effort and understanding of the problem.

What I would like to know is whether this effort would be enough to contribute to one's thesis, or if I should change my approach and forget about implementation aspects.

My supervisor has been very hands-off so far. He said that it was great that I was studying the topic and trying implementations, but, so far, he has not given me any concrete topic or direction. He hired me for this position knowing that I lacked theoretical knowledge on the research topic (let's say neural networks), but he said that he was interested in other experiences that I had.

Comment: I'm sorry, we don't answer field-specific questions.

Comment: Consider going into industry, where (especially for this field) you can get paid significantly more while also being more results-focused.

Comment: There is no fundamental reason why a method of running NNs on embedded systems couldn't be a novel contribution to the advancement of human knowledge.

Comment: Perhaps find someone in an engineering department working on embedded systems?

Comment: In the research field of software engineering, there is now a somewhat trendy topic of "software engineering for AI" which deals with questions such as those you mention: instead of developing new AI algorithms, the focus is on how to make the available AI algorithms work in real-life settings.

Comment: "Compared to how I feel about implementing these algorithms and methods, I feel only moderately interested in ... diving deep into the theory of neural networks" - but do you care about the *theory* of the implementation (like how fast different operations are on different architectures, the mathematics behind certain functions more efficiently estimating other functions, etc.)? Because simply implementing algorithms without working on theory doesn't sound like much of a topic for research (although there are plenty of industry jobs where you can do that, and get paid well for doing so).

Comment: @NotThatGuy Not all research in computing is on (algorithm) theory. In software engineering, one of the main research paradigms is empirical software engineering, which has very different notions of theory than classical computing theory.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Even if you're mostly implementing stuff, you still need to be forming, testing and validating theories for it to be research, which is my point. The question that OP needs to figure out is whether they care about those theories, or whether they just want to be told "here's an algorithm, go and implement it". Although they may be able to find research where the theories are a small enough part for it to be what they're looking for.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I do care about the theory behind it. My question is more in the sense whether implementation aspects can be considered research itself. Maybe a more concrete example: let's think about the FFT algorithm. Fourier transform was not something new at the time, but the FFT algorithm explored the implementation side I guess. Could the FFT algorithm be considered research? It focuses on implementing something which is not necessarily new.

Answer (score 15):

This depends entirely on your university and, in particular, on what your advisor is willing to approve. Convince them and it works, otherwise not.

Many fields have applied subfields so it isn't impossible in theory, but in practice it depends on your advisor unless you are willing to change. No one here can overrule anyone at your university.

And maybe you need to build a better (closer) relationship with your advisor.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I definitely thought this was a clear yes or no question. I agree with your last point, but what does a closer relationship actually means?

Comment: Just wanted to say that if I remove "neural networks" my PhD thesis was almost exactly matching OPs description - I focused on implementation of AI in the context of video games using existing algorithms, but taking into account the specific constraints of the use case (especially low budget for computations) and it was possible precisely because my supervisor was interested in that kind of stuff... (link to thesis: http://popelka.ms.mff.cuni.cz/~cerny/thesis/disertace_cerny.pdf)

Comment: @MartinModrak Which, of course, means that work that duplicates yours may well no longer be sufficiently novel to be published.

Comment: @nick012000 That seems as unfounded fear to me - as I mentioned, I didn't use neural networks and I just explored a very tiny bit of surface even in the relatively narrow space of "practical AI for video games", so there's IMHO plenty of space for other good work even in very similar area and the OP's proposal is very likely in a substantially different area.

Answer (score 5):

Talk to your advisor. Even if they are hands off, you can take the initiative to ask for a short meeting and directly ask them, "I am interested in doing X, Y, and Z for my thesis, would you find that acceptable?" From what you've written, I am guessing they will say some variant of either "yes" or "that's fine but for balance and/or to connect with other work in our lab it would also be good if you include some other topics like A, B, C."

Comment: Good point. I guess it would be way better to ask for adjustments in a direction than for a direction altogether.

Comment: @wasntme Definitely. Often, this type of advisor is looking for you to take initiative and express your interests -- if you wait for them to talk to you, you will likely slip through the cracks. Even if you don't have a perfect plan, going to them with some ideas for what you can work on for your thesis will be a really good starting point for a discussion and show that you can take responsibility for your own studies.

Answer (score 5):

Oh, if it's about the topic you mentioned, then you should definitely not be discouraged the slightest, as long as your supervisor can benefit from your research in some way.
A lot of people work on theory and hardware-independent ideas in deep learning, but without the usage of a specific hardware component (the GPU), deep learning would have never established itself the way it did.

There is definitely a whole subfield in deep learning that tries to push the boundary of what is possible on smaller devices.
Here are a few examples (I'm not working in this subfield, so take it with a grain of salt):

https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.03048

https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09274

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0045790621001257

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41565-020-0722-5

https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11946

Comment: Thank you for your input. I guess the bottom line would be that implementation aspects could be considered as research?

Comment: +1 ... this is called low-SWaP computing and is a very active research area, both on the hardware side and in terms of writing algorithms that can run on such hardware. This is quite different than "I don't care about theory and just want to write code" (which is also fine, but not really a fit for a CS PhD).

Comment: @wasntme yes, definitely. But you always have to be able to motivate it for your supervisor. Research is not about theory, but about coming up with and answering questions. If you can state an important/impactful/interesting question and can argue how your new approaches in implementations can tackle this question, then you are most likely good to go. Keep in mind that 'important/impactful/interesting' can be very subjective and your supervisor has the last word on this.